# EventHandlers in python, anything like C#? Listening for serial messages

Tags: python, event-handling

Is it possible to have EventHandlers in Python like C#.

In C# I have an Event Handler for receiving data over a serial port, this stops the need for listening in a loop.

Like this:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    InputData = ComPort.ReadExisting();
    if (InputData != String.Empty)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });

        if (InputData == "0")
        {
            WriteToLog("COM IN = 0 GetFileNames");
            GetFileNames();
        }
        if (InputData == "1")
        {
            WriteToLog("COM IN = 1 GetFileCount");
            GetFileCount();
        }
        if (InputData == "2")
        {
            WriteToLog("COM IN = 2 GetFolderSize");
            GetFolderSize();
        }
        if (InputData == "3")
        {
            WriteToLog("COM IN = 3 Restart PC");
            RestartPC();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any analogous way of doing this in python? as currently I am listening like this and it seems wasteful as it's just sitting there ticking away.

```
import time
import serial


ser = serial.Serial(

    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
counter=0


while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    print x
```

Comment: You have the library reactiveX for Python https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY. That could help you to build Observable and observer events

Answer (score 1):

```
import can

class Event:
    def __init__(self):
          self.handlers = set()
    def handle(self, handler):
        self.handlers.add(handler)
        return self

    def unhandle(self, handler):
        try:
            self.handlers.remove(handler)
        except:
            raise ValueError("no handler...")
        return self

    def fire(self, *args, **kargs):
        for handler in self.handlers:
            handler(*args, **kargs)

    def getHandlerCount(self):
        return len(self.handlers)

    __iadd__ = handle
    __isub__ = unhandle
    __call__ = fire
    __len__  = getHandlerCount


class BufferedReader(Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = queue.Queue(0)

    def on_message_received(self, msg):
        self.buffer.put(msg)

    def get_message(self, timeout=0.5):
        try:
            return self.buffer.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
        except queue.Empty:
            return None

class MockPortWatcher(BufferedListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bus = can.interface.Bus('Event', bustype='virtual')
        self.portChanged = Event()
    def watchPort(self):
        source_path = "/dev/ttyS1"           
        msg = self.get_message()
        self.portChanged(msg)

    def get_message(self):
        msg = self.bus.recv()
        return msg

    def log_port_change(msg):
        print "%r we got message to handle:" % (msg)
```

since the question is to follow c# lang event syntax, we got much the same with python:

```
watcher = MockPortWatcher()
watcher.portChanged += log_port_change
watcher.watchPort()
```

Comment: "python-can" hides the low-level, device-specific interfaces to controller area network adapters in interface dependant modules. However as each hardware device is different, you should carefully go through your interface’s documentation. For example, to use over serial ports like /dev/ttyS1 or /dev/ttyUSB0 on Linux machines or COM1 on Windows, the can over serial  interface is used - https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/interfaces/serial.html

Comment: serial port bus could be created like 
```self.bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='serial', channel='/dev/ttyS10') ```